# What is the Equvalent N1ql query for inserting the document in the couchbase

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-java-api

The following query is for fetching the documents from the couchbase while working with Java_client

```
 N1qlQueryResult result = bucket.query(N1qlQuery.simple(
                    "SELECT * FROM `default;"));
```

How to write the statement to insert the docs into Couchbase using N1qlQuery like above?

Answer (score 4):

Since 4.1, N1QL also have `INSERT` and `UPSERT` statements that you can use to create documents. See [the reference (INSERT)](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/insert.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a document using the `insert(...)` method from the `Bucket` class. For example:

```
JSONDocument resultDoc = bucket.insert(JSONDocument.create(myId, myJSONDocument));
```

where both `myId` and `myJSONDocument` are strings.

For future reference, you can always refer to the [Couchbase JAVA SDK](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.3.1/).